# Jenkins refuses to start - unknown argument --ajp13Port=-1

Tags: linux, debian, jenkins

My jenkins installation on Debian was upgraded (using apt) - and now jenkins refuses to start.  I can see the following in the log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
     Unrecognized option: --ajp13Port=-1
```

My jenkins version is 2.381.  Unfortunately, I now don't know which version was installed prior to this, but it definitely worked and no config changes have been made.

How can I get it to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. File `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf` contained the following line:

```
Environment="JENKINS_OPTS=  --ajp13Port=-1"
```

I commented this line - and the service started without an issue.

Looks like the upgrade process (via apt) doesn't deal with the configuration overrides correctly.

Comment: It does. overrides are supposed to NOT be touched by apt.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same message on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and Jenkins 2.375.1. It almost looks like the parameter isn't supported anymore. Removed it from /etc/default/jenkins and it started again.

Comment: I hope `Ubuntu 9.4.0` is a typo.

Comment: I'm no admin, I tried ... now better?